# exit of csh shell do not abort the execution immediately

Tags: shell, posix, csh, tcsh

The manual of (t)csh say:

> exit [expr]
>                  The shell exits either with the value of the specified expr (an expression,  as  described  under  Expressions)  or,
>                  without expr, with the value 0.

But if run `tcsh -c 'exit 5; echo after exit'; echo $?`, we get the following output (test on tcsh of ubuntu/centos and freebsd 10.3):

```
after exit
0
```

It seems like the `exit` command is skipped. How to get the same action like the POSIX/bash shell?

Comment: I find adding a `eval` will cause the exit works as expect (`csh -c 'eval exit 5; echo after exit'; echo $?`). But it is still very difficult to understand the csh script.

Comment: csh -- having a hand-written parser rather than a machine-generated one -- is rather well-known for behaving in surprising and unexpected ways. Is there a reason you aren't using a POSIX-compliant shell instead?

Comment: I'm running some bsd machines, and writing some csh shell codes. pattern of `need-run-following-script || exit 0; following-script` is very common, but it is really surprising that the `following-script` is always run.

Comment: BSD machines have POSIX-compliant shells. And yes, that *is* surprising, but csh is full of surprises.

Comment: OK, i do not really depend on `csh`, but am curious about the reason or the culture of `csh` shell, is this by design or just a bug?

Comment: Couldn't say. Serious folks moved off csh decades ago (see http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt, http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot, etc). It was popular when there weren't other good choices (ksh cost money, Bourne wasn't friendly for interactive use), but that was a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do in a POSIX shell? If you want to print something and exit normally just do `printf "%s\n" 'my message'; exit 0`. (See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo for reasons not to use `echo`)

This is probably a bug in `csh` that's kept in `tcsh` for backwards compatibility reasons.

`(t)csh` is line-oriented in a way that other shells are not and generally processes input a line at a time, for instance

This script:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
exit 5
echo 'after exit'
```

exits with status 5 when executed.

This script, on the other hand, prints `after exit`.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
exit 5; echo 'after exit'
```

Somewhat more surprisingly, a string containing a newline passed to `/bin/tcsh` is treated like the single-line script, not the multi-line one.

```
% perl -e 'system("/bin/tcsh -f -c \"exit 5\necho after\"")'
```

Comment: Hi, why `csh -c 'eval exit 5; printf after_exit'` this works as expected, but `csh -c 'exit 5; printf after_exit'` print `after_exit` and exit 0?