# Why does tcsh execute the next command after exit?

Tags: shell, tcsh

Disclaimer: Yes I know tcsh is terrible for programming.

Why in the world does tcsh do this? It does exit, but not with exit code 1, and after it executes the next command.

```bash
$ tcsh
> echo hello ; exit 1 ; echo world
hello
world
exit
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: No idea! Is this reproducible? I would do a `set echo` before, in the hope that this reveals some insight.

Comment: Linking in history (not a duplicate IMHO): https://stackoverflow.com/q/42768940/4957508

Comment: @user1934428 yes, tried it on my phone with termux and on my computer

Comment: Well, and what does _set echo_ show?

Comment: echo hello\nhello\nexit 1\necho world\nworld\nexit